# Use WebBrowser and OnNavigatedFrom back history WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have a webbrowser in my project Windows phone 8.
I want to make the browser type Internet Explorer.
My problem is in a back button.

in a OnNavigatedFrom i'm insert this code:
WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");

but close the xaml page

not exists in a OnNavigatedFrom e.cancel=true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for override [OnBackKeyPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - when Back key is pressed, not [OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - which is fired when you leave the `Page`:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  // you should check for example if there is history 
  if (history exists)
  {
    WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  // else normal navigation - exit page - to fulfill certification requirements 
}
```

It is one the buttons you can override, but be aware that to fit [Certification requirements - 5.2.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you need to handle it properly. It must provide Navigation and Exit App.